# Humorous quote about some minor indiscretion leading to a major crime

Tags: quote-source

There is a humorous quote by Oscar Wilde or somebody about one minor bad act leading to a major bad act.  This isn't it, but it was like this:

> Don't wash your hands today, then you'll start shop-lifting harmonicas
> tomorrow, and be committing murder the day after.

Does anyone recognize something like this?  It sounded Wildean, but it could have been Jack Benny, for all I know.

Comment: I say, first, medicinal wine from a teaspoon  
Then beer from a bottle   
And the next thing you know   
Your son is playing for money in a pinch-back suit ...    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LI_Oe-jtgdI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If once a man indulges himself in murder, very soon he comes to think
> very little of robbing, and from robbing he comes next to drinking and
> Sabbath breaking, and from that to incivility and procrastination.
>
> --De Quincey

The quotation is from De Quincey's ["Second Paper on Murder considered as One of the Fine Arts"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Second_Paper_on_Murder_considered_as_One_of_the_Fine_Arts).

Comment: That has the feel of an inversion or parody of an existing well-known quote or saying.